# Graph Theory Minors

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a graph which is edge-maximal without a $K_{3}$-minor, but not extremal among those without $K_{3}$-minor? (That is, can you provide two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ both without $K_{3}$-minor such that (a) adding any edge to $G_1$ creates a $K_{3}$-minor and (b) $G_2$ has MORE edges than $G_1$? If not, why can no such pair exist?)

Comment: Are $G_1$ and $G_2$ on the same number of vertices? Did you have any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Have you given any thought toward what it means to have a $K_3$-minor?

Comment: To have a K$_{3}$-minor means that after edge contractions you would end up with a planar graph with three vertices and whatever edges may be left after doing so. I have tried drawing some pictures, but I'm not succeeding.

Comment: And yes we are assuming that both graphs have the same number of vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If a graph has a cycle, can you create a $K_3$ minor? What type of graphs don't have cycles?

Comment: So, then after some thought you would have to have a tree because they are edge maximal, any edge you add would create a cycle which could be contracted to a triangle (K$_3$-minor). Hence, the answer would be no?

Comment: @Lindsey That's right, all trees on a given number of vertices have the same number of edges.